# javascript- check if value of object in array is not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this simple array with objects and values, but not all objects have same values:

```
var array = [
    {name: '‏aaa', mobile: '111-111'},
    {name: '‏bbb', mobile: '222-222', adress: '333-333'},
    {name: '‏ccc', mobile: '444-444', adress: '555-555'}
]
```

the first object doesn't have an address.

so when I tried to append it to html I got `undefined` word:

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul').append(
    '<li>‏'+array[i].name+'</li>'+
    '<li>‏'+array[i].mobile+'</li>'+
    '<li>‏'+array[i].adress+'</li>'+
)}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>‏‏aaa</li>
<li>‏111-111</li>
<li>‏undefined</li>

<li>‏‏bbb</li>
<li>‏222-222</li>
<li>‏333-333</li>
```

how can to check if this value not exist then show nothing instead of `undefined` word?, or even to not show the whole `li` tag?

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWs3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has an inherent Boolean value, generally known as either truthy or falsy. A unassigned value will return false in an if statement ie 
`if(array[i].adress){`
I added a shorthand if statement to your code to fix the problem.

```
function details () {
$('ul').append(
    '<li>‏'+array[i].name+'</li>'+
    '<li>‏'+array[i].mobile+'</li>'+
    (array[i].adress? '<li>‏'+ array[i].adress +'</li>': '')
);
}
```

Comment: Your `if` is better than mine.  I forgot that `undefined` is `falthy`.

Comment: Thnk you @Bryan, that's what I want :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to set it's adress still but with `' '` value.

```
var array = [
    {name: '‏aaa', mobile: '111-111',adress:''},
    {name: '‏bbb', mobile: '222-222', adress: '333-333'},
    {name: '‏ccc', mobile: '444-444', adress: '555-555'}
]
```

**EDIT** :

**SOLUTION 2**

check if `array[i].adress` is `typeof` `Undefined`

```
function details () {
    if( typeof array[i].adress == "undefined"){
         array[i].adress = '';   
    }
    $('ul').append(
        '<li>‏'+array[i].name+'</li>'+
        '<li>‏'+array[i].mobile+'</li>'+
        '<li>‏'+array[i].adress+'</li>'+
        '<br />'
    );
}
```

Fiddle updated : [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWs3/9/)

Comment: I have hundreds of elements and about 15 values for each element, so i can't change them manually

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var array = [
    {name: '‏aaa', mobile: '111-111'},
    {name: '‏bbb', mobile: '222-222', adress: '333-333'},
    {name: '‏ccc', mobile: '444-444', adress: '555-555'}
];

$.each(array, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(key, val) {
        $("<li>", {
            "text": val
        }).appendTo("ul")
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/mU9T5/

Comment: Yes, this is much elegant in some aspect. +1

Comment: Great solution. +1  ([Added in the break between li](http://jsfiddle.net/mU9T5/1/))

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
function details () {
    $('ul').append(
        '<li>‏'+array[i].name+'</li>'+
        '<li>‏'+array[i].mobile+'</li>'+ 
        (typeof(array[i].adress) === 'undefined' ? '' :
        ('<li>‏'+array[i].adress+'</li>')) +
        '<br />'
    );
}
```

I used ternary `if` with the condition that checked whether `address` property was defined.  If not, the entire `<li>` is omitted.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZWs3/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Waht you are looking for is this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7U3r/

- `hasOwnProperty` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property.

Hope this fits your needs `:)`

**code**

`array[i].hasOwnProperty('adress')`

Comment: @AhmadSeraj yep, thats why this `hasOwnProperty` method exist. no need to do raw `undefined` cheacks when the method does it for you. and in optimality it might be faster `:)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
 if (array[i].adress==null)
{
     array[i]['adress'] = 'None';
}
$('ul').append(
    '<li>‏'+array[i].name+'</li>'+
    '<li>‏'+array[i].mobile+'</li>'+
    '<li>‏'+array[i].adress+'</li>'+
    '<br />'
);
```

Comment: in this way all the values of an element that doesn't have address value will disappear , and that not what I want

Comment: Try this one simillary you can add else if for name and mobile